# How to convert UV position to texture atlas pos and reapply to UV in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, uv-mapping, mesh

I'm trying to apply a texture from an atlas to a mesh by reiterating through the UV array on that mesh, but I'm a bit lost on converting the coordinates.

For example, if the texture required is at x,y pixels on the material texture atlas, how can I convert and get those coordinates and apply to the mesh? I'm redrawing meshes dynamically with a chunk loader for a voxel game, I have it down for square voxels but now when adding more complex meshes, need to know how to apply the texture to these.

I imagine the code would be something like, but I'm hoping someone can help me fill in the blanks:

```
   void UpdateMesh()
   {
       UVList.Clear();
       Mesh mesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
       for (int i = 0; i < mesh.uv.Length; i++)
       {
           UVList.Add(GetUVTextureFromAtlas(mesh.uv[i].x, mesh.uv[i].y, voxelType);
       }
      mesh.uv = UVList.ToArray();
   }
  //converts UV position expected from mesh model to position on texture atlas
  Vector2 GetUVTextureFromAtlas(float x, float y, int voxelType)
  {
        Vector2 uv;
        Vector2 textureAtlasPos = GetTextureOffset(voxelType); // returns texture pos from atlas

      //not exactly sure what this would look like for code to convert 
      //from the position on the atlas to the expected UV position based on
      //expected UV position (i.e. from 1,0 to whereever the texture is on the atlas)

        return uv;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base UVs exist on a unit rectangle:

```
    (0, 1)            (1, 1)
    +-----------------+
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    +-----------------+
    (0, 0)            (1, 0)
```

You're trying to map that space to a different rectangle on the atlas:

```
    (xmin, ymax)      (xmax, ymax)
    +-----------------+
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |                 |
    +-----------------+
    (xmin, ymin)      (xmax, ymin)
```

Since your base UVs range from `0` to `1`, it's trivial to use `Lerp`:

```
float xout = Mathf.Lerp(xmin, xmax, x);
float yout = Mathf.Lerp(ymin, ymax, y);
```

You'll need appropriate values for `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, and `ymax`, which means you need to know the location and size of the texture on the atlas.

I've also assumed that those four values are in UV-space. If your atlas coordinates are specified as pixel coordinates, you can convert those to UV coordinates with `InverseLerp`. Suppose you have a texture at `(x, y)` with size `(xlen, ylen)`, on an atlas with size `(xsize, ysize)`:

```
xmin = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, xsize, x);
xmax = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, xsize, x + xlen);
ymin = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, ysize, y);
ymax = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, ysize, y + ylen);
```

It's absolutely possible to improve on this method, if you're comfortable with the math, but that's the basic gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was great explanation and I sincerely appreciate it.